# How to draw a charcter to screen on pygame

Tags: python, pygame, screen, draw

How do you draw an ascii character to the screen in pygame?
All I have been able to find is how to draw a rectangle with: 
`pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width,height), thickness)`.

I was wondering if there is a way to draw a character on the screen such as 'A' and have that appear on screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
font = pygame.font.Font(<Font>, 36)
text = font.render("<Char>", 1, (10, 10, 10))
textpos = text.get_rect()
<Surface>.blit(text, textpos)
```

EDIT: Note that the names between the greater/less signs are placeholders...

Comment: Good answer @LPK - can you expand a little bit on it - for example, put what tipical values for "<Font>" would be? (I think a default Font is alaways present)

Comment: I think you can use None actually

Comment: Or use one of the system fonts with pygame.font.SysFont()